# Ajax Database example from w3schools jquery driven

Tags: ajax, jquery, lazy-evaluation

Hello i need the code from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp rewritten in jquery(if possible) but more important for my project is on load the first customer to be already gathered from the db and eliminate the Please select option.
Anybody could help me please .. I'm trying to do a kind of select sort/filter based on this example for my website,

Thank you

Comment: This is more of a "write lots of code for me" request - those are frowned upon on SO. I would recommend starting work on it yourself and ask when you have a specific question, or to get paid help

Comment: You are right .. please answer me then only to the second part of the question... leave it Ajax and eliminate the Please select option .. on load to show first selected .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it myself .. but thanks for the votes :) I will add here maybe somebody will be interested

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name='customers']").attr("selectedIndex", 1);
    $("select[name='customers']").change(function() {
        var str = $(this).val();
        if( str == "" ) {
            $("#txtHint").html("");
        }
        else {
            $.get("getcustomer.asp", {"q": str}, function(data) { $("#txtHint").html(data) });
        }
    }).change();
});
```